# PHP read .xlsx file then use 'foreach'?

Tags: php, foreach, spreadsheet, xlsx

I would like to know how to read a .xlsx file using PHP script then use 'foreach' function to display each category of my spreadsheet, for example; I need to display a menu that has 'starters', 'main course', 'dessert' and 'drinks' but within a category it has item name, item number, descriptions and price.

So it will displays 'starters' -> 'item name' -> 'item number' -> 'descriptions' -> 'price'.

I can't provide the spreadsheet file yet since I'm outside posting from my mobile, but I need some assists from this issue I have. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't what you need supported by [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)? If not, please provide more detail on your specific requirements and especially the input data.

Comment: I will also suggest "Phpexcel". This is best

Comment: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/07reader.php

Best example for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Spout](https://github.com/box/spout) to achieve what you want. Here is an example:

```
$reader = ReaderFactory::create(Type::XLSX);
$reader->open('/path/to/your/xlsx/file.xlsx');

$items = [];
foreach ($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) {
    foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        // here, you have access to each row, as an associative array
        $category = $row[0];
        $itemName = $row[1];
        $itemNumber = $row[2];
        $description = $row[3];
        $price = $row[4];

        // then do whatever you want with this data
        // for instance:
        $items[$category] = [
           'name' => $itemName,
           'number' => $itemNumber,
           'description' => $description,
           'price' => $price,
        ];
    }
}

$reader->close();
```

Comment: Man, first of all thank you very much! Secondly I really like you provided me an example, that really help me A LOT in my learning period where I got no idea how PHPExcel works and there're so many functions that you just can't think from your mind but you have to search and go through things. (I'll still learn but my time is limited to complete my project) That's why I need some examples like you gave! Much appreciated! Unfortunately I can't 'mark' as useful due to low reputation now. I'll come back and vote after that :)

Comment: Ahaha no pb! I'm glad it helped. PHPExcel is a comprehensive library so it can be a bit intimidating to start with. Spout has less functionalities but as a result is simpler to use. Feel free to keep asking questions if you have any other issues

Comment: Hi I got an issue where I needed to layout each items like this  http://imgur.com/46uDryG but in this http://imgur.com/VYsjtrP you can see it displays multiple of 'Starters'. I tried to use `array_unique` but won't work... Got any idea how to display in each category? like my example 1? Also Is there any idea I could scans its category then generate a navbar like picture?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I got problem print/echo them out I got errors `Notice: Array to string conversion in menu.php on line 65` my line 65 `print $items;` tried `echo and print_r` too

Comment: BIG Thanks for helping me out, much appreciated